# Parametrize $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

How can we parametrize the surface $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$? Here I mean differentiable parametrize.

I think we may need to divide it into 8 pieces and consider them respectively.

Comment: Do you mean you want differentiable parametrization? If not $x=s$, $y=t$, $z=\pm (1-|s|-|t|)$ works. Not sure what additional conditions you want to impose.

Comment: Yes.  There are $8$ cases, by choosing signs for each variable independently.  The graph is a regular octahedron with vertices $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1, 0)$, and $(0, 0, \pm 1)$.

Comment: @user44197 Yes, I mean differentiable parametrize

Answer (score 2):

Then as you pointed out, there are 8 possible cases.
$$
\begin{align}
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=s, y=t, z=1-s-t \\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=s, y=t, z=s+t-1\\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=-s, y=t, z=1-s-t \\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=-s, y=t, z=s+t-1\\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=s, y=-t, z=1-s-t \\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=s, y=-t, z=s+t-1\\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=-s, y=-t, z=1-s-t \\
0\le s \le 1, 0 \le t \le 1-s &: x=-s, y=-t, z=s+t-1\\
\end{align}$$